# Mysql slow joining small (20k) rows table to large (5mil) rows table, with indexes

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-optimization

I have two tables, devices (20k) rows and device_logins (5 mil rows), each device_logins row has a device_id with a foreign key and index linking to devices.

I'm trying to create a list of every week which a device was used in and from what applications, using MySQL, but it takes roughly 3 seconds to execute which stacks quickly in the application and from what I've read that's not enough data to justify taking that long

The schema is:

```
[devices]
id int unsigned
user_id int unsigned; foreign to users; index
hardware_type varchar
os_type varchar
os_version varchar
first_use datetime
last_use datetime
deleted_at datetime null
```

```
[device_logins]
id int unsigned
user_id int unsigned; foreign to users; index
device_id int unsigned; foreign to devices; index 
application string
login_date datetime
```

The query is:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT appLoginToDeviceInRange.application SEPARATOR ', ') AS dataSource,
       weekList.weekStartDate                                                                                                                         AS date,
       MIN(devicesInRange.id)                                                                                                                         AS eventId
FROM (
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%u')                                                    AS week,
           DATE_FORMAT(date - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(date) DAY, '%Y-%m-%d')                    AS weekStartDate,
           DATE_FORMAT((date - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(date) DAY) + INTERVAL 6 DAY, '%Y-%m-%d') AS weekEndDate
    FROM (
        SELECT '2021-07-11' - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a) + (1000 * d.a)) DAY AS DATE
        FROM (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS a
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS b
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS c
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS d ORDER BY DATE DESC) AS `dateList`
    GROUP BY `week`
    ORDER BY `weekStartDate` DESC
    ) AS `weekList`
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT `devices`.*
        FROM devices
            INNER JOIN `users`
            ON `users`.`id` = `devices`.`user_id`
                AND users`.`id` IN (13368)
        WHERE `hardware_type` = 'MOBILE'
    ) AS `devicesInRange`
    ON `devicesInRange`.`first_use` <= `weekList`.`weekEndDate` AND `devicesInRange`.`last_use` >= `weekList`.`weekStartDate` AND
       (`devicesInRange`.`deleted_at` IS NULL OR `devicesInRange`.`deleted_at` >= `weekList`.`weekStartDate`)
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT `device_id`, `application`, YEARWEEK(login_date) AS loginWeek
        FROM `deviceLogin`
        WHERE `device_id` IS NOT NULL
    ) AS `appLoginToDeviceInRange`
    ON `appLoginToDeviceInRange`.`device_id` = `devicesInRange`.`id`
    AND `appLoginToDeviceInRange`.`loginWeek` >= YEARWEEK(weekList.weekStartDate)
    AND `appLoginToDeviceInRange`.`loginWeek` <= YEARWEEK(weekList.weekEndDate)
WHERE `weekList`.`weekStartDate` < '2021-07-16 15:02:09.176280'
GROUP BY `os_type`, `week`
ORDER BY `weekList`.`weekStartDate` DESC, `os_type` DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Removing the join to my table with 5 million rows makes it take 80~ms as you'd expect and I've run mysqltuner and configured accordingly

Answer (score 0):

- Pre-build `dateList`, reaching far into the future; have the `PRIMARY KEY` on that date column; `JOIN` with a `WHERE` limiting to the desired range of days (or weeks).
- Build and maintain a "Summary" table that contains each days counts.  Then use that for tallying up over the desired day's (or week's).  More:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables
- If you might ever want info for "days", then use "DAY" in the above suggestions, else use "WEEK".  Even reading from a daily summary to get weekly amounts will be reasonably fast.  (And much faster than reading from the raw data, like you are doing now.)
- If `'2021-07-16 15:02:09.176280'` came from `NOW(6)`, you may as well simply say `NOW(6)` or, probably, `CURDATE()`.  (No speed improvement, just clarity.)
- `JOIN (SELECT ...) ON ... JOIN (SELECT ...) ON ...` is often inefficient; ponder whether some other formulation would work.
- Perhaps you want `FROM weekList LEFT JOIN ...` to provide zeros if a week has no data?  (What you have will, I think, simply leave out such weeks.)  (Not for performance, but for 'correctness'.)
- Please qualify `hardware_type`, `os_type`, etc with the table they are in.  It makes it easier to know what is going on, especially when trying to determine optimal indexes.  (An `INDEX` cannot span two tables.)
- Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so I can help with indexes.
- `GROUP BY x ORDER BY y` requires an extra temp table and sort -- when `x` and `y` are different.  Your

  ```
    GROUP BY  `os_type`, `week`
    ORDER BY  `weekList`.`weekStartDate` DESC, `os_type` DESC
  ```

could probably be turned into

```
    GROUP BY  `weekList`.`weekStartDate`,      `os_type`
    ORDER BY  `weekList`.`weekStartDate` DESC, `os_type` DESC
```

- Fix those things up; then come back for more advice if it is still "too slow".  (There will be so many changes that it would be best to start another Question.)